# EditText maximum characters limit exceeded callback

Tags: android, android-edittext

My idea is to set an error `View` to the `EditText` when the maximum character limit has been reached. Is there any callback about this event, or may be there's another way to achieve this effect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the edit text's [`setError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {         
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() > max)
                editText.setError("Error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm limiting the maximum length using android:maxLength attribute in XML, so I doubt this will work for me.

Comment: which will not work because the length will never be too long because of the maxLength

Comment: You asked for "another way to achieve this result". This is one,move your maxLength to a constant and implement this.

Answer (score 11):

maxLength attribute in the EditText is actually an InputFilter, which you can write yourself and supply from code.

You can look at the implementation of InputFilter.LengthFilter, which basically returns null if there is no overflow. (see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/InputFilter.java#InputFilter.LengthFilter.filter%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%2Cint%2Candroid.text.Spanned%2Cint%2Cint%29 )

you can create an extension to InputFilter.LengthFilter in which you call super and compare it to null to decide if you need to display an alert.

### edit - with code

```
editText.setInputFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max) {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            CharSequence res = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
            if (res != null) { // Overflow
                editText.setError("Overflow");
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: great solution! elegant and useful

Comment: Perfect. For those working in Kotlin, when you `override fun filter(): CharSequence?` make sure that return type is nullable `CharSequence`, with a ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use [TextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and check the length of the EditText test versus your limit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but-

```
editText.setFilters() not editText.setInputFilters()
```